# Python - Django - Model BooleanField Dependent On Other BooleanField In Same Model

Tags: python, django, boolean, models

I am using Django to write a web application and would like to know if it is possible to have a BooleanField within a model for which the value will be based on other BooleanFields in the same model.

Basically, I would like one BooleanField in the model to be True only if all other BooleanFields in the model are True.

For example, with the Model below:

```
class ModelEx(models.Model):
   booleanA = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   booleanB = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   booleanC = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   booleanD = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I would like booleanA to be True only if booleanB and booleanC and booleanD are True.

I have not found any information about this so it would be great if anyone knew if there is a solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the save method of your model.

```
class ModelEx(models.Model):
   booleanA = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   booleanB = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   booleanC = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   booleanD = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.booleanA = self.booleanA and self.booleanB and self.booleanC
       return super(ModelEx, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: instead of passing the kwargs in save, do `def save(self, *args, **kwargs)` then call the parent's save with them `super(ModelEx, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Also, `True` + `True` + `True` is 3 not `True`. If e.g.  `booleanD` was `False`, then `booleanA` would be 2. Use `self.booleanB and self.booleanC and self.booleanD` instead

Comment: Thanks such keen eyes.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. @Bipul I will validate your answer as it did put me in the right direction. Evans Murithi was indeed correct with his comment so credit to you as well for giving the exact answer. I have one more question though. When amending the data directly from the DB interface, changing all fields to true does not change field A to true (even though it works perfectly when changes are triggered by the view functions). Would you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the save method of model. It will be like this.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   self.booleanA = self.booleanB and self.booleanC and self.booleanD
   return super(ModelEx, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hi shivam, thanks a lot for your answer. This is correct but the answer had already been provided so I have marked the first one as the correct one.